# How to handle sinch hangup call for incoming call notification

Tags: android, sinch, incoming-call

I just recently started working on sinch SDK. And i'm confuse about how to handle  incoming call if caller has already hanged up call before repentance got to accept incoming call. there is now method how handle this situation. Here is my code where i'm handling inconimg call

```
sinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new CallClientListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, final Call call) {
            mAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(HomeActivity.this);
            mAudioPlayer.playRingtone();
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.incoming_call_notification);
            dialog.setTitle("Incoming Call");
            TextView callerName = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.incoming_caller_name);
            CircularImageView callerProfileImage = (CircularImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_incoming_call);
            Button pickCallBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.incomming_call_pick_up);
            Button hangUpCall = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.incomming_call_hang_up);
            pickCallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
                    call.answer();
                }
            });
            hangUpCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
                    if (call!=null){
                        call.hangup();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If the caller hangup before the callee answer you will get a callDidEnd event during the answer scenario.

Comment: is this method is the part of CallListener ?

Comment: yes, https://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/index.html?com/sinch/android/rtc/SinchClient.html its called onCallEnded